# Expand Parent DIV to dynamic child elements

Tags: html, css

Firstly, I realise that many question have been asked on this subject, but I have reviewed all of them (that I can find) and yet none of them appears to solve my problem.

I have a parent DIV (.timeline) that I want to hold a variable number of tables representing months/days.  As I scroll horizontally I will dynamically add more months and this works, but I can't get the parent DIV to expand width to accommodate any new tables.

Here is the current HTML:

```
<div h-buffered-scroll="timeCtrl.adjustTimeline()" class="timeline">

        <div class="wrapper">
            <table ng-repeat="obj in timeCtrl.tLine">   
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="monthhead" colspan="{{obj.days}}">
                            <div class="fixed">{{obj.monthYear}}</div>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th ng-repeat="day in timeCtrl.dayRange(obj.days) track by $index">
                            {{$index+1}}
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td ng-repeat="day in timeCtrl.dayRange(obj.days) track by $index"
                            id="{{obj.y}}_{{obj.m}}_{{$index+1}}"
                            ng-class="timeCtrl.isWorkDay('{{obj.y}}-{{obj.m}}-{{$index+1}}') ? 'work' : 'hol'">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

</div>
```

And here is the relevant CSS:

```
.timeline {
    position: relative;
    height: 90%;
    width: 95%;
    margin-left: 25px;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    border-radius: 2px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}

.timeline div {
    min-width: 1000%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
}

.timeline > div > table {
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

I have the min-width:1000% just to set the parent wide enough to start with but ideally I expect I should not need to set a value for this is should just expand to fit however many child tables I create.  What is happening is that the first two tables fit into the 1000% but then the next table (i.e. next month) then goes under the first two tables as it exceeds the width of the parent container.

Below is what I am trying to achieve:

```
+--------------------+
|+-----+ +----+ +----|--+  table 3 expands beyond parent div
||  1  | |  2 | |  3 |  |  and should be able to scroll to see
||     | |    | |    |  |
|+-----+ +----+ +----|--+
+------<-scroll->----+
```

I've tried to set the display to inline-block on the wrapper but this doesn't help

Comment: Try adding `white-space: nowrap` to the `.timeline` and `white-space: normal` to the tables, along with `display: inline-block`.

`nowrap` value will stop the div's children from creating new lines of content.

Comment: An example: https://jsfiddle.net/svzbtkqk/

Comment: Thanks @VictorGodoi, will give it a go an let you know

Comment: Genius @VictorGodoi, All working now - seems that the float:left that I had on the table was causing an issue as well (so I removed it), but with your suggestions it is now working like a dream !!!  Many thanks